# Visa validity for airline boarding

Tags: visas, schengen, tickets, qatar-airways

My German visa validity is from 19-Feb-2019.

I have booked qatar airways flight from India which has departure at 19-Feb 3.45 AM IST. The time in Germany would be 18-Feb-2019 11:15 PM CET.

Would I be allowed to board the flight considering my visa would not be valid at that time with respect to CET.

I called qatar twice and got two different answers, probably I was not able communicate clearly via phone.

I might be overthinking it, But since this is my first time I am a bit anxious.